# Бесконечный роутинг

Tags: kohana

Можно ли в кохане сделать такой роут, чтобы в качестве дополнительных параметров принималось бесконечное множество этих параметров. Что-то вроде такого:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>/<id>/<id>/<id>/<id>/<id>/...)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Опишу свою проблему: пишу фронт к базе modx и мне нужно разбирать таблицу контента на категории и материалы. т.к. kohana не дружит из коробки с контроллерами и экшенами вида сonroller-name (а такие очень нужны в урлах), решил брать все пути из БД и формировать из них ссылки.

Но хотя опять же, если скажем мне не нужна бложенность более 3х, то можно ли оставить такую конструкцию и будет ли это правильно?

```
Route::set('sections', '(<id>(/<id2>(/<id3>(/<id4>))))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Comment: а зачем такая вложенность? Практика показывает, что роута <directory>/<controller>/<action>/<id> хватает, если не на всё, то на 90% случаев точно

Comment: что есть "контроллерами и экшенами вида сonroller-name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы разрешить всё, что угодно - делайте разбор вручную, либо дополняйте маршрутизатор. Намного проще первое. Для этого укажите регуляркой, что параметр может содержать всё:

```
Route::set('mad_route', '(<request>)', array('request' => '.*'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'controllername',
        'action'     => 'actionname',
    ));
```